# Family-relative teacher? (Correct wording)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Let's say you are a **teacher** who is a **family member** at the same to one of your students (such as uncle-niece) Your opinion is that sometimes, it's a bit awkward. You say:

> Being a **family-relative teacher** can cause uneasiness, because your approach becomes different from what you normally would as a **non-family relative teacher.**

I'm not only describing the *bold letters* using the adjective-noun combination to avoid *verbosity*, but also in an advanced way to express it. However I'm not sure if those (bold letters) are grammatical/correct description, cause I've just combined them, which I've never heard of in my entire life.

Comment: The expressions "family-relative teacher" and "non-family relative teacher"  are not common in English.  Please do some simple Googling and check whether you are correct or not.

Comment: I had already done that before this posted question, nothing came closer to what I'm asking here.

Comment: Then you know it's not idiomatic. Just keep to "*…a teacher who happens to be a relative ..... to a teacher who is unconnected to your family*" It may not be succinct but it's clear.

Answer (score 3):

family-relative teacher

**That phase simply does not work to express the idea of a person being a teacher who is related to one of her/his students.**

Being a teacher with a family member in one's class is [etc.]

As a teacher, being related to one of one's students is [etc.]

Being related to a student one teaches is [etc.]

Generally, one cannot use a hyphen between two nouns and expect to come out with the complicated relationship being described.

Comment: I am looking for a phrase, if there's any, to say what I actually is trying to say, not describing it. Still, the options here are a good way to say it correctly.

Comment: There is no phrase per se.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed sentence is not idiomatic.

"Teaching a relative can cause uneasiness because normal techniques may not be appropriate or effective" is what I think you are trying to say.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm trying to say here, but the "family relation to a student when one is a teacher"...

Comment: I may indeed have failed to understand the full complexity of what you want to convey. A "relative" and a "member of the family" mean the same thing. The concise and idiomatic word to use here is "relative," not "family-relative." Because what you say in your comment that you want to say has no verb, it has no meaning. Where do you think my answer needs clarification or amendment?

Comment: First off, thx for the correction on family=relative thing hehe. Whereas, my answer to your question is the "approach"... I'm not asking that, sry man.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with it, but you'd have to also use *non-family-relative teacher*. It's starting to get a bit convoluted though. I'd tear it down and make it a lot simpler.

Being a family relation of a student can cause uneasiness and your approach to become different than it would otherwise be.

You don't need to add the ..if you weren't related. It's already clear.